# Cannot get blocshop TCP sockets-for-cordova to work

Tags: sockets, tcp, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

Need to have an Ionic mobile app connect to a Java Tomcat application server using TCP sockets. Have done the following:

Per the **blocshop** site (https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova) directions installed the plugin with: **cordova plugin add cz.blocshop.socketsforcordova**

Added script **src="socket.js"** below **script src="cordova.js"** in the index.html file.

When run in a debug mode in WebStorm the construct **var socket = new Socket();** results in the error: **ReferenceError: Socket is not defined**

Any assistance on how to get blocshop TCP sockets-for-cordova to work in an Ionic project is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing socket (`var socket = new Socket()`) after `deviceready` event is called.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with `cz.blocshop.socketsforcordova` and the fix was:

- Update Phonegap/cordva
- Update the android SDK
- Remove the platform executing `android cordova platform remove android`
- Install the android's platform using cordova (first time I used phonegap platform add android) `cordova platform add android`

After following those steps my problem was fixed :)